# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Dynamic Collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am searching for a solution to a resizing issue with bootstrap's navbar.

Currently a navbar can have a sort of 'overlapping' effect before becoming compacted. (I am aware that this is due to media queries)

[image: example from bootstraps site]

Media queries are being used here to dictate when to go compact, however I am looking for a solution that will cause the navbar to resize ONLY when there is no room left between '.navbar-nav' and '.navbar-right'.

This is significant because '.navbar-nav' and '.navbar-right' have dynamic widths. (in other words sometimes '.navbar-nav' will contain anywhere from 1 list item to 5 list items. '.navbar-right' is similar in that it is a string of text that could be anywhere from 3 characters to potentially 100 characters long or even longer.

[image]

Below is a plunker example where by resizing the preview pane, you can see the unintended 'overlapping' taking place (as it waits for the max-width media query to be met).

http://plnkr.co/edit/7r5fNX2JyJUuT0PvVPDf?p=preview

How can I have it become compacted only when '.navbar-nav' and '.navbar-right' have no room between each other (say.. 5px of space between each other or something similar)?

*(please note, adjusting the break points is not enough to accomplish this)*

Comment: Javascript is an option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add a custom class on your navbar, and change the style when it gain height :

```
<nav id="autocollapse" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    ...
</nav>
```

```
function autocollapse() {
    var navbar = $('#autocollapse');
    navbar.removeClass('collapsed'); // set standart view
    if(navbar.innerHeight() > 50) // check if we've got 2 lines
        navbar.addClass('collapsed'); // force collapse mode
}

$(document).on('ready', autocollapse);
$(window).on('resize', autocollapse);
```

```
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
#autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/98963)**
**[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g6gRVAt2y1w64SfSrm5X?p=preview)**

Comment: Plain and simple! Thanks chief!

Comment: Quick and.... dirty a little bit I would say. Well, the expected height of the navbar of 50px won't change that often i guess but to perfect it I would compare against the height of an menuelement instead of hardcoded 50px. :)

Comment: @burebistaruler It still works with BT 3.1.1 : [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/120904). You probably have another problem.

Comment: @zessx your example works only on chrome browser , on firefox and ie10 is not working :|

Comment: @burebistaruler Mmmh... It seems more complex (I don't have the time to investigate right now). If I use preview buttons (fullscreen and/or mobile), it works on Chrome, but not on Firefox. **But**, if I manually resize my window (without preview), it works on both browsers.

Comment: When I try the link of bootply(120904) above in Google Chrome, and I make the window smaller so it collapses , when I click to get the menu it disappears again. So it's not working since you can't select the menu items. Same behavior in Ipad, not on Iphone. Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: instead of the fix 50px height you could add something like $("#autocollapse ul > li").getHeight() so get the height of one element and could use this instead

Answer (score 4):

May be worth a try with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width_full = $('.navbar-collapse').innerWidth();
    var width_left = $('.navbar-nav').outerWidth(true);
    var width_right = $('.navbar-right').outerWidth(true);
    if (width_full - (width_left + width_right) < 0)
    {
        // trigger collapse, you have to figure out what css changes
        // exactly are needed, for example:
        $('.navbar-toggle').css('display', 'inline');
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry... it has to be < 0 not >= 0 obviously, changed it now.

Comment: Yeah, if the menu items are dynamic and you really want the resize to be dynamic, then this jQuery example is probably the easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for CSS to detect the line-wrapping by itself, so you'll need to redefine the styles for a particular width of media. You're line-wrapping appears to be happening around 910px;

Twitter Bootstrap (3) by default applies `display:none` to `.collapse`, and then reapplies `display:block` value using a media-query to a detect view-port width of greater than or equal to 768px width:

```
/* beginning at line 4412 in bootstrap.css,  v3.0.2 */  
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    ... /*other declarations ommitted here */

    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block !important;
        height: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }

    ... /*other declarations ommitted here */
}
```

So you could override this with a couple of more specific media-queries for your navbar for the range of values where you need to hide it (between 768px and 910px):

```
@media (min-width: 768px)  and max-width (max-width: 910px){

    #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{

        display:none !important;
    }
```

Comment: There's an easier answer. There's several places that min-width:768px takes over for the BS3 menu, including the little bars, so you can either use less and edit the variables.less file or use the customizer and stick in whatever width you want to get it to switch to the toggle.

Comment: But that will redefine the behavior for every possible usage. I would generally advise against editing the library CSS (LESS) file itself, for the trouble it brings when upgrading to a new version, and for tracking the changes that you've made (the source is thousands of lines of code)

Comment: I see now. Never use the customizer, just thought that would be the fastest. The breakpoint  for the navbar should be separated IMO.

Comment: It is not a matter of mediaqueries, as captainrad mentioned twice. I think you will need javascript to make the adjustments,

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 3.3.5 some styles are missing for [zessx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238019/zessx) answer. use these ones instead:

```
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }       
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }       
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    #autocollapse.collapsed .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #autocollapse.collapsed .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
```

One more thing. [zessx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238019/zessx) uses 50px for collapse. There's a round issue when you applies a Zoom to the explorer. The nav height could be 53px, for example, and then the menu will collapse. I suggest to change the 50px value to 70px. So here is my suggest:

```
function autocollapse() {
            var navbar = $('#autocollapse');
            navbar.removeClass('collapsed'); // set standart view
            if (navbar.innerHeight() > 70) // check if we've got 2 lines
                navbar.addClass('collapsed'); // force collapse mode
        }
```